# Square Orders created in api not showing in live dashboard

Tags: square-connect, square

I used #square guide to create an order in square API but the order only shows on backend using the search_orders call but not on the live dashboard.Here is what I did

```
##Step 1 create order
order={}
order['location_id']=location_id
#not sure how best to have this
order['reference_id']= "011"
line_items=[]

quantity="1"
measurement_unit={}
measurement_unit['generic_unit']="UNIT"
quantity_unit={}
quantity_unit['measurement_unit']=measurement_unit
quantity_unit['precision']=1
note="TEST ORDER BY PETER"
base_price_money={}
# base_price_money['amount']= catalogue_price
base_price_money['amount']= 0
base_price_money['currency']=catalogue_currency

line_item={}
line_item['catalog_object_id']=catalogue_id
# line_item['name']= catalogue_name
line_item['quantity']= quantity
# line_item['quantity_unit']=quantity_unit
line_item['note']=note
line_item['base_price_money']=base_price_money

line_items.append(line_item)

order['line_items']=line_items

fulfillment={}
pickup_details={}
pickup_details['note']='TEST Order forwarded from Feedr'
pickup_details['pickup_at']=datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
recipient={}
address={}
address['address_line_1']=""
address['administrative_district_level_1']=""
address['first_name']="PETER"
address['first_name']="TEST"
recipient['address']=address
recipient['display_name']= "Peter Test  Forward"
recipient['schedule_type']= "SCHEDULED"
pickup_details['recipient']=recipient
fulfillment["pickup_details"]=pickup_details
fulfillment["state"]="PROPOSED"
fulfillment["type"]= "PICKUP"
fulfillment["uid"]= "6"

order['fulfillments']=[fulfillment]

body={}
body['order']=order
body['idempotency_key']=str(uuid.uuid1())


result = client.orders.create_order(location_id=location_id, body=body)


if result.is_success():
  print('done')
elif result.is_error():
  print(result.errors)
```

#Step 2 pay for the order created, with a zero since order is paid for from another system

```
result = client.orders.pay_order(
  order_id = result.body.get("order").get("id"),
  body = {
    "idempotency_key": body['idempotency_key'],
    "payment_ids": []
  }
)
if result.is_success():

  print('done')
elif result.is_error():
  print(result.errors)
```

3. When I search the orders using below call, I see the orders I have created but they are not on dashboard

```
orders_api = client.orders

body = {}
body['location_ids']=locations
body['return_entries']= False
result = orders_api.search_orders(body)
```

Not sure what am missing

Comment: This looks correct. Could you provide a order_id so I can take a look?

Comment: ETGW8SQhDS1JaImfF46XONi2U19YY

Comment: @sjosey see above. I also noticed I couldnt find the customer ids on the portal in the backend. I had a hunch maybe The issue was since I hadnt created a customer id

Comment: ah, figured it out. The idempotency_key needs to be different. In Orders all writers are the same when it comes to idempotency (create/update/pay, etc), so since it was the same, it didn't actually "pay" for the order.

Comment: @sjosey I tried to use a different idempotency key for the payments and it went through

Comment: How do we assign an order number for orders on the dashboard. Any ideas?

Comment: No way to at this time, unfortunately. This is only available through Weebly/Square Online Store.

Comment: @Mushirih are your orders appearing on the dashboard or pos? I am following the same process as you've described. The order then appears as a transaction in Square, but not as an order.

Comment: I solved it and they appeared in the dashboard

Comment: Thanks, I realized I wasn't adding the fulfillment properly. Now they appear.